# How to know which select tag option has been changed by the user

Tags: forms

In my webpage, I have a form which has multiple fieldset elements. Each fieldset element has a select tag with some options, and depending upon which option has been selected, the input fields in the fieldset are changed. But, how can I know the user changed the option on which select tag?

```
 <select onChange='selectHandler();'>
 <option value='0'>Option 1</option>
 <option value='1'>Option 2</option>
 <option value='2'>Option 3</option>
 <option value='3'>Option 4</option>
 </select>
```

I can get all the select elements using getElementsByTagName('select'), but how to know extactly which element the user selected?

Comment: You have mentioned in the example code itself the "onChange" this will help you identify. What is the difficulty here?

Comment: In the selectHandler() , I get an array by document.getElementsByTagName('select');. I want to know which element of the array the user interacted with, similar to getting all checkboxes on the page and then finding out the marked checkbox with checkboxes[i].checked.

Comment: Pass the 'this' keyword in the select handler like 'selectHandler(this)'. You can get which select element is accessed.

Comment: I exactly did that. If you add this as an aswer, I will mark it as accepted

Comment: I have added that as the answer in the elaborated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solves your problem

Pass the 'this' keyword in the select handler like 'selectHandler(this)'. You can get which select element is accessed

```
<select id="handler1" onChange='selectHandler(this);'>
 <option value='0'>Option 1</option>
 <option value='1'>Option 2</option>
 <option value='2'>Option 3</option>
 <option value='3'>Option 4</option>
 </select>

function selectHandler(obj){

   console.log(obj.id) //It gives the id of the current select tag
}
```

Don't use document.getElementsByTagName('select');. This will give you only array of object and you will not know which select tag has been clicked.